# Whats exact definition of 'atomicity' in programming?

Tags: linux, concurrency

the definition of 'atomicity' says that a transaction should be able to be terminated without being touched or manipulated by possibly concurrent running actions during its process. But does that also mean that a program should not run concurrent when it is supposed to be atomic?

let's say we have 2 program as an example:

example_program1:

> counts int i = 1 to 100 every second
>
> every number is printed in new line

example_program2:

> just prints "hi"

and a parent program that includes both of these program and run them once receiving a signal to start a specific program (e.g via sigaction in linux) with 2 version:

version 1:

> runs the program (even concurrent) anytime once receiving the signal
>
> which means program2 can print "hi" while program1 is still printing out the numbers

version 2:

> only run one program at a time
>
> signal for other program is blocked until program in progress has terminated

in this example, can only version 2 considered atomic or both? Would this program be non-atomic only if e.g program2 would increment i by 1 during its process?

Comment: This is a very complex topic, and would be more appropriate for asking in [cs.se].

Answer (score 0):

Hi Atomic operations provide instructions that execute atomically without interruption. Just as the atom was originally thought to be an indivisible particle, atomic operations are indivisible instructions.

I will like to explain that with a program multithread production and consumer with rase conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>


pthread_cond_t condicion = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int cont = 0;

void* productor(){
while(1){   
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while(cont != 0)
  {
    pthread_cond_wait(&condicion, &mutex);
  }
  cont++;
  printf("%d\n",cont);
  pthread_cond_signal(&condicion);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
}

void* consumidor(){
while(1)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while(cont == 0)
  {
    pthread_cond_wait(&condicion, &mutex);
  }
  cont--;
  printf("%d\n",cont);
  pthread_cond_signal(&condicion);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }
  }

 int main(){


pthread_t id_hilo1,id_hilo2;

pthread_create(&id_hilo1, NULL, &productor, NULL);
pthread_create(&id_hilo2, NULL, &consumidor, NULL);

pthread_join(id_hilo1, NULL);
pthread_join(id_hilo2, NULL);

return 0;
}
```